# Rotate the polycut by 90 degrees

Tags: unreal, unreal-5

If I want to make a hole in a vertical wall, I would use the polycut from the modeling toolbar, right? But the tool shows up in the horizontal plane, and if you want to rotate it, it seems like the only way is to drag one of the circles on the gizmo. And I can never get it upright. And it doesn't snap. And the cut is not even on both sides, cause it's at an angle. Can I enter the value manually somewhere? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: seriously? nobody will touch this?

Comment: not even a single person?